# Does magnetizing steel increase tensile strength?

Tags: material-science, ferromagnetism

I can't help but think that it would since even two separate pieces of magnetized steel that are just touching will have some "tensile strength".

Though, I would guess that even if the answer was yes, the effect would be small compared to the normal tensile strength due to direct atomic bonds.

But with my own physics knowledge, I can't be sure that there isn't some kind of quantum mechanical trickery going on that causes just enough of the existing tensile strength to be "shifted" into the magnetization that leaves the overall tensile strength unchanged or even weakened when a bit of metal becomes magnetized.

Comment: *I can't help but think that it would since even two separate pieces of magnetized steel that are just touching will have some "tensile strength"* why? because of their magnetic attraction?

Comment: @lineage Yeah, in essence, tensile strength is the ability of a material to resist stretching or bending, which some magnets stuck together do to some extent.

Comment: so if you applied glue between two objects would that count as increasing the tensile strength of the object or of the composite pair?

Comment: @lineage The composite pair.

Comment: there's your prelim answer-increased resistance to tensile stress from external modifications of the material like magnetic attraction to other things, being tethered to ground, glued, etc. don't count as an increase in tensile strength. Beyond this, the effect of allignment of electron spins on tensile strength--don't know about that

Comment: On the one hand, it is clear that a ferromagnetic material has additional magnetic terms in the Gibbs free energy that make the ferromagnetic phase more stable than a non-magnetic phase. At first blush you might think that makes it stronger, since it would take more energy to pull it all apart. However, tensile strengths in non-brittle materials depend more on just how the material fails, such as slip systems. These are somewhat less amenable to a blanket statement relating bulk free energy to tensile strength.

Comment: @lineage That doesn't serve as an answer, because in the question at hand we're not talking about gluing two separate objects together. It's about how magnetization affects the tensile strength of a composite object where the individual components are atoms and it already has a positive tensile strength. Where as two pieces of unmagnetized steel could be said to have zero tensile strength as a composite object. Trying to find the answer to the question in the analogy that gave my intuition I think confuses the question.